# How to change a point to circle in a Graphics expresion

Tags: graphics, replacement, geometry

Given the following line of code,

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.02], 
  Point[{9, 5}], Point[{2, -5}], Point[{5, 5}], Point[{3, 6}],Point[{1, 1}], 
  Point[{5, -7}], Point[{-7, 4}], Point[{6, -10}], Point[{-6, -2}], Point[{0, 8}], 
  Point[{1, 4}],Line[{{1, 4}, {2, 5}}], Point[{2, 5}]}, 
  AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

the objective is to replace every Point as a Circle with a radius of 1/2 centered around the same coordinates. The question asks for this to be done using a ReplaceAll (aka Rule) function.

I know how to replace points with circles. Just add `/. Point -> Circle` to the end of that block. And it goes from [plotted dots](http://i.gyazo.com/3ef265fa57a184cc89095a0551855b05.png) to [circles](http://i.gyazo.com/160a24f3a5e89ef24c69b386d9e30a90.png).

But how do I change the radius to 1/2 using the Rule function? Because when I replace Point with Circle, it results in Circle of radius 1. The only way I could think was something like `/. Point[{ _ , _ }] -> Circle[{ _ , _ }, 0.5]`, but that of course didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could try yourgraphics /. Point[x_] -> Circle[x, 1/2]

Comment: Look up `Blank`.

Comment: This is my take on using Blank. 

/. Point[{_, _}] -> Circle[#, 0.5]

It doesn't work, however. Can someone please explain what I did wrong/need to change?

Comment: @FredSimons it doesn't work :(

Comment: On my computer, it works. But it might be that somewhere you did an assignment to x. Then use :> instead of -> (RuleDelayed instead of Rule)

Comment: @FredSimons Nice catch! Yes, I forgot to Clear[x] before trying your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g = Graphics[{PointSize[.02], Point[{9, 5}], Point[{2, -5}], Point[{5, 5}], Point[{3, 6}],
    Point[{1, 1}], Point[{5, -7}], Point[{-7, 4}], Point[{6, -10}], Point[{-6, -2}],
    Point[{0, 8}], Point[{1, 4}], Line[{{1, 4}, {2, 5}}], Point[{2, 5}]}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];
g /. Point -> (Circle[#, .5] &)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you explain what the &'s purpose is? How does it affect the output? Thanks very much!

Comment: Also, how come Circle[#, .5] & must be enclosed in standard parentheses (as opposed to square/curly/no brackets)?

Comment: @AisforAmbition, questions like your first can be easily answered using the built-in documentation. Just highlight '&' and press F1. You need the second hit (`Function`). As to your second question: This has to do with operator precedence. Precedence of `->` is higher than `&` and the pure function `Circle[#, .5] &` needs to be protected from being read as `(Point -> Circle[#, .5] )&`. You can find the precedence table on the [tutorial/OperatorInputForms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) page of the documentation.